# easy-going vs easy going

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

Which one is correct:

> Clive never worries. He's really **easy-going**.

OR

> Clive never worries. He's really **easy going**.

As per my understanding, hyphen comes between compound adjectives if they are before noun; so the correct one is second one. But as per BBC website correct one is first one with hyphen.

Answer (score 3):

Use the hyphen or the solid form to mean 'relaxed': you are using an adjective, and many compound adjectives which include verbs tend to be at least hyphenated wherever there's even a possibility that the reader might parse the compound could be misread as two separate words (assuming the author is paying attention).

[Going is also a noun](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/going_1) which can refer to the quality of a journey, especially the rate of progress, and "easy going" could mean a straightforward and effortless journey.

Answer (score 1):

I know what you mean here. Hyphens are essential to avoid ambiguity, especially without compound adjectives:  for example a hyphen is the difference between a man eating squid and a man-eating squid.  Therefore, I would suggest that Clive is easy going without the hyphen as there is no confusion there.

Comment: Except what the OP is really saying is: "He's a really easy-going guy". He's just rephrased the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

ODO lists [easygoing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/easygoing), a single word with no hyphen, in the US English dictionary. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=easygoing%2Ceasy-going%2Ceasy%20going&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceasygoing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceasy%20-%20going%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceasy%20going%3B%2Cc0) shows that this usage has been more common since the 70's.

In the British and World English dictionary, they have [easy-going](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/easy-going), with a hyphen. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=easygoing%2Ceasy-going%2Ceasy%20going&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceasygoing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceasy%20-%20going%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceasy%20going%3B%2Cc0) concurs, although the usage in general has dropped significantly in the past few decades, and it's getting closer to *easygoing*.

In both Ngram searches, *easy going* as two words is far less common.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either so long as they make sense;  whether or not you choose to hyphenate  this compound adjective does not matter.